# Parent controller lost a property's value assigned from child controller

Tags: angularjs

In my angularJs (1.5), on the landing page (landingPage controller) I have a navigation page link, by clicking the navigation link it pops up a modal which is built using $uibModal bootstrap service and it's attached with it's own controller. The uibModal's controller and the template are inline to the parent controller (landingPage's controller).

My problem is, the value assigned to a parent controller's property from the uibModal controller is lost when I revisit the landingPage controller after the modal's inputs submitted.

1. go to the landing page
2. Click the orgLink and fill up the modal and click submit button on the modal.
3. During the second point above, the modal controller assigns a derived value (tempId) to the main controller's property. ex: `this.orgVo.orgId = tempId;`  //tempId is a derived value in modal controller.
4. return to the landing page after modal submit.
5. Click the orgLink again, check for the assigned value in  `this.orgVo.orgId`, but lost.

Comment: When you are returning to the page do you mean you are closing the modal or actually reloading the page after form submit?

Comment: After the modal is submitted (closes modal) with inputs the user will be back to the landing page and when the user clicks the orgLink again the execution enters the main controller second time and it will check for the modal assigned value in `this.orgVo.orgId` to not to pop the modal again. so modal will display only when there is no value in **this.orgVo.orgId**.

Comment: I understand that the user will be back to the page but there's a difference if the page reloads or the modal gets hidden if the page reloads you lose the scope anyways

Comment: @Yousef, I understand that in my case I should hide the modal instead of closing it to retain the property values. I use '$uibModalInstance.close()' to close the modal and don't know if I can use '$uibModalInstance.hide()' to hide the modal

Comment: If you are using close then what am asking is not relevant I thought you had a form that you submit and then it reloads the page

Comment: So the bottom line of my requirement is how to update parent scope variable from child. I can access very well the parent scope variables but the changes made to them from child are not retained in the parent. Any help please.

Comment: Finally I have fixed by creating reference object for parent scope in the child and assigned new value to the reference object's property. Found the updated value is retained in the parent's scope.